# How to set an image either for an Order or for a Line Item in Google Assistant Applications

Tags: actions-on-google

1 . I build my Order like this:

```
let order_id = uuid();
let cart = app.BuildCart()....

let order = app.buildOrder(order_id)
            .setCart(cart)
            .addOtherItems([
                app.buildLineItem('Subtotal', 'subtotal')
                    .setType(app.Transactions.LineItemType.SUBTOTAL)
                    .setPrice(app.Transactions.PriceType.ESTIMATE, 'USD', 0),
                app.buildLineItem('Tax', 'tax')
                    .setType(app.Transactions.LineItemType.TAX)
                    .setPrice(app.Transactions.PriceType.ESTIMATE, 'USD', 0)
            ])
            .setTotalPrice(app.Transactions.PriceType.ACTUAL, 'USD', 0)
            .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/dLk6jwO.png', 'some text');
```

and everything works just fine except the fact `setImage` does not cause any affects on the screen.

Why my image is not visible? What am I doing wrong?

2 . I did not give up and tried to set an image to a Line Item as well:

```
let cart = app.buildCart().setMerchant('book_store_1', 'Book Store')
            .addLineItems([
                app.buildLineItem('memoirs_1', 'My Memoirs')
                    .setType(app.Transactions.LineItemType.REGULAR)
                    .setPrice(app.Transactions.PriceType.ACTUAL, 'USD', 0)
                    .setQuantity(1)
                    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/dLk6jwO.png', 'blah blah blah')
                    .addSublines('Note from the author'),
                 ]);
```

But this did not help.

Can anyone tell me why I can't set an Image? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the cart object neither the line item has the setImage method. There is no mention of it from what I've could see from their documentation.

Comment: I didn't say that the Cart has this method. The Order does. And the Line Item does.
[setImage of an Order](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/Order#setImage) and [setImage of a LineItem](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/LineItem#setImage)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug. 
I will report it internally and keep you posted.
Thank you for reporting it!

Comment: Thank you! Looking forward to the fix :)